# ylim how to expand / define / set ymax + 2*SD

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a small problem with ylim and ggplot2.

I am displaying `geom_text` just above error bars in ggplot and I don't know how to define ylim to always include this text inside the plot. Sometimes text is outside or half cut.

I want to ylim was max data value plus SD from this maximum and plus some space for text (2*SD for example).

I dont want to define ylim manually every time.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (instead of ):

```
max_val <- max(data$value)
# in ggplot call:
# ggplot(data ...) ... +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max_val * 1.2))
```